# How to hide sender email address using phpmailer?

Tags: php

I am using phpmailer to send email. I need to know how to hide or mask sender email address

Comment: For what purpose? Many servers won't let you do that. And it has an evil smell.

Comment: Do you have a good reason for doing this? (Pro tip: there is no good reason.)

Comment: Since we need to show our company email address as sender. since we didnt have any email server. Help me Now i am using gmail server port to send msg using gmail account

Comment: There is no point in doing this. as your email will just go to spam inbox if its "hidden".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a rare situation you have here... if you do not have a mail server you can still tell PHPMailer to send from a different address just set the `From` attribute of the `PHPMailer` object to the address you want. But Wait! if your server doesn't exists, the client can't verify the account and then your mail will more likely be deleted (moved to spam in the more benevolent scenario). If you are trying to mimic third party mail, I'll help you no futher.

**Note**: Your mail server may be valid but clients are still unable to verify it, and thus you are getting mails delivered to spam or deleted. Check "Must Read" to below to have some inside on how to solve this.

On the other hand, if you already have a mail server, then tell PHPMailer you want to use it, set the `Host` and `Port` attributes to your domain name and port respectively. The same if you want to use an account form a different server, remember to set the attributes `Username` and `Password` correctly, you may also need to set `SMTPAuth = true;` and `SMTPSecure = 'ssl';` depending on the server. [Note: `Username` and `From` may differ]

---

Now, if you want to use an account from Gmail, you could easily set an alias in Gmail to send as another account [Go to Settings-> Accounts And Import -> Send mail as -> (click) Send Mail From Another Address], that can be the case if you have a mail server but you cannot afford to have it online, you will need to start your server so you can receive the confirmation code Gmail generates to verify your account. Check recommended read for PHP side configuration details.

---

Lastly if for some rare circunstancies you can't tell PHPMailer to use your mail server, but you do in fact have one, and that one is able to recieve the mail... you can use `AddReplyTo('me@example.com', 'My Name');` Most clients will understand that any reply to the message must be (unless explicitly defined by the user) directed to "me@example.com" in this case.

**Disclaimer**: I take no responsibility of any harm result of the use of the method I mention here, such as (but not limited to) your mail account getting banned.

**Must read**:
[Coding Horror on sending mail via code](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html)

**Recommended read**: [PHPMailer Tutorial](http://www.askapache.com/php/phpfreaks-eric-rosebrocks-phpmailer-tutorial.html) ([old version](http://web.archive.org/web/20100819041054/http://www.askapache.com/php/phpfreaks-eric-rosebrocks-phpmailer-tutorial.html))

No need (neither a good way) to hide or mask whatsoever.

Answer (score 15):

You can specify any sender email address anyway, since SMTP by itself does not place any requirements on sender email addresses.

If the actual SMTP server you use places restrictions on email addresses (e.g. corporate servers which do not allow sender emails outside of the company domain) there's no way around that, unless of course you can influence the mail server configuration.

**Update:**
You say in a comment that you want to use gmail to send email where the sender's address is not a gmail address. There is no way to do that.

Comment: I don't think that answer deserves a downvote, so +1. Google won't let you send mail using a different `From` header.

Comment: Would it be possible to create an alias within that gmail account, as you can within the gmail settings, to send email as a different address...that is possible, so it "may" be possible to pull it off if you set that address as an alias in the gmail settings. Worth a shot.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you already know how to use the class you are talking about. 
You probably have some variable for sending email, like 
`var $From = "someguy@whatever.com";`
you can type whatever you want into that email address. Gmail dont care what email things is sent from. 
And no, this dosent sound very legit. 
One more thing: Gmail requires a gmail account to relay mails. Its no problem, it wont be visible.

Comment: I have done this at some time, yes. Of course, gmail may have changed policy.

Answer (score 0):

You want to "show the company email address as sender" but you "didn't (sic) have any email server"?

Can anyone actually send you email at your company email address?  If so, use that server which is hosting your email to send out from.

If you don't really have a company email address, then I suggest you get a gmail address like companyname@gmail.com and just send from that.  Otherwise the email will appear as spam to a great many of your recipients.

Now, if the people you are about to send an email to actually signed up to be on your mailing list then you can use a third party application like Constant Contact to do your broadcasts from.

If they haven't, then I suggest you not send an email at all.

Answer (score 0):

in mail headers you can have both a `Sender:` and a `From:` header which in most mail clients is displayed as either just the `From` or in some cases `Sender` on behalf of `From`, using this way is a nice and clean way to be able to send `From` a different mail address then the actual `Sender` mail server

Answer (score -3):

This is highly illegal.

```
 var $From = "someguy@whatever.com";
```

Is the only option your have for trying to hide email address. But no matter what your email will be inscribed with IP. Someone who knows what they are doing will still be able to trace the email back to the source.

Comment: Ok maybe not illegal but immoral would be more likely. I guess it could be usefully internally in a company but I mean you can really mess with someone sending fake emails from lovers, co-worker and shit like that.

Comment: I used to telnet to open relays and send emails from whitehouse.gov ALA GTMHH back in the day.  Its the way it was designed, email is not to be trusted.

Comment: Yeah, unless you can trace its signed IP.