# Hide SMTP address in PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Im using phpmailer to send mails with my gmail smtp server. My code looks like this:

```
$mail->IsSMTP(); 

$mail->Host     = "smtp.gmail.com"; 

$mail->Port       = 465;

$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";

$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Username = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";  

$mail->Password = "xxxxxxx"; 

$mail->From     = "xxxxxx@domain.com";

$mail->FromName = "Domain";

$mail->AddAddress("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxx");

$mail->AddReplyTo("xxxxxxxxxxx@reply.com","Me");
```

so, when i receive this email it shows me "Domain" as the sender, thats correct, but when i look at the address it shows me "xxxxxx@gmail.com and not xxxxxx@domain.com. I dont want it to show the smtp sender address. It should show the "from" address.

Another small thing, i dont know if thats even possible. When i reply to my mail, it will show the reply name and the reply adress, is it possible to hide the real address? Like it shows xxxxxxx@real.com but actually the reply goes to xxxxxx@fake.com?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide sender email address using phpmailer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518900/how-to-hide-sender-email-address-using-phpmailer)

Comment: is gmail allowed to pose as your domain? they could be properly ignoring the address if they're not allowed to - otherwise you could be using `From = president@whitehouse.gov`.